# Upgrading the Google Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I'm having some difficulties upgrading the Chrome browser. This is the upgrade reminder from Gmail today:

[image]

My current version on about:version is:

[image]

Then, I uninstalled the current Chrome browser (using `apt-get autoremove google-chrome`), and download the newest version from https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html:

[image]

I see the new version in my Ubuntu Software Center:

[image]

However, after reinstalling this .deb, I still get the old version!

[image]

What did I do wrong??

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just an conflict with the website and the current version of Chrome.  I am told all the time I am not using IE and IE is the only browser supported, except I am using, its just IE11 and the script is broken.

Comment: @Ramhound  Sorry, I don't quite understand you. Even the version number from the .deb is different from what's installed.

Comment: So you believe the .deb file is not installing the correct version?  I missed the `about:version` initially.  Disregard my earlier comment.

Comment: @Ramhound I have found out the solution.. Even after shutting down the chrome, I need to use `pkill` to kill all chrome threads. Then I have the correct version after restarting chrome. Thank you!